# How to give a class method a function interface?

Tags: typescript

You can define a type signature to closures using `interface`:

```
interface IFn {
    (a: string): string
}
```

Docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#function-types

This works when assigning the interface type to variables.

But can I assign this interface to a class method.

Something like this:

```
class X {
    someFn: IFn {

    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The interface you've defined defines a type which is an object with a function. So you'd need to do something like the following (naming the function:

```
interface IFn {
    someFn(a: string): string
}

class X implements IFn {
    someFn (a: string) {
return 'foo';
    }
}
```

If you really wish to specifiy a type signature of your function separately from your class interface you could do so:

```
type SomeFn = (x:string) => string

interface IFn {
    someFn:SomeFn
}

class X implements IFn {
    someFn (a: string) {
return 'foo';
    }
}
```

It's not possible to specify the method signature in your class method itself because any type signature written here would imply the return type of the function.

You can also create multiple interfaces if you wish and your class can `implements` from multiple. I'd question what you are aiming to achieve though.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#function-types This implies that the example interface in my question is for the type signature of a function? Can I apply this to class methods?

Comment: Thanks, I guess that Typescript does not support applying interfaces directly to class methods. So the intermediate interface that applies to the class is always required?

Comment: I tried this and it works! However it seems that you have to type the implementation (again) nonetheless. Any idea if there is a reason for this? Or could it be considered a "missing" feature?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```js
interface IFn {
    (a: string): string;
}

class X {
    public someFn: IFn = function (a: string): string {
        return a;
    };
}
```

Comment: Similar. I want to apply the interface directly to a class method (not to a closure stored on a class property).